# onbeforeunload works different on Chrome than it does on Firefox. I am looking for any potential alternatives

Tags: javascript, web, onbeforeunload

I am trying to add a `onbeforeunload` to my code so it fires a message that is sent to a server. I am encountering the following issue:

- On page refresh, the message is sent to the server when using Firefox. It does not send a message to the server when I refresh the page on Google Chrome.
- When clicking on links on my site to navigate to different sites, the server gets a message only when using Chrome. Firefox does not send a message when clicking on external links.

I also know that `onbeforeunload` is supposed to work when the window is closed, you enter a different website and navigate to that. There are some additional cases which also trigger the function. My site does not work with any of these along with the errors mentioned above.

If there a fix to this? If so, what can I do? I have looked around to fixes but I only get fixes where it prompts the user on whether they want to leave the page or not, I do not want that.

Additionally, I tried adding the function call to `onclick` on my external links but that is not being triggered on Firefox. I am guessing this is due to the amount of time `onbeforeunload` has before it is cancelled. If so, there a way around this?

Lastly, if this is not possible with `onbeforeunload`, what are my other options without prompting the user if they want to leave or not.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Here is some code that can be used:

https://jsfiddle.net/985drboy/

Comment: This requires a [example] so that you can reproduce the problem for us.

Comment: @RandyCasburn I have edited the post with that. Here is the hosted code: https://jsfiddle.net/985drboy/

Comment: @RandyCasburn Basically, everything works with jsfiddle but not when using the Firefox or Chrome browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure, that your code sending the message to the server is blocking and not async. If `onbeforeunload` returns before your message is sent, you get undefined behavior e.g. your message might not be sent if the page is unloads before the sending was complete. The browser continues unloading as soon as `unbeforeunload` returns.

Comment: How exactly would I go about using blocking and not an async function? I am currently using fetch. I believe fetch is async so what would I need to do to make it blocking. I put the code online: https://jsfiddle.net/985drboy/, in case you would like to test it and change it.

Comment: You could use `await` I think.

Comment: No, await is still async - the same result will occur.

Comment: I added `await` to the function but it still requires me to add `return function()` which prompts the user for either 'leave page' or 'stay on page'. Like Randy Casburn said, `await` still is async so this won't work unless I use `return` when calling `<body onbeforeunload="">` which is unfortunately not what I am looking for.

Comment: The solution would be to trap the event (`preventDefault()`), wait for your AJAX request to complete, `.then()` navigate away to the final destination programatically.

Comment: @RandyCasburn could you show me an example of what you said? I pretty new to JavaScript and I cannot find an example of what you said. Sorry for the hassle!

Comment: @RandyCasburn Thanks! It works for the links but it still prompts the alert about leaving the page when refreshing or closing the window. I am assuming there is no way around this?

Comment: I want to clarify, after further testing, this sometimes work when closing page and pressing "leave page" but only on FireFox. I have tested it on Chrome and it does not work, for some reason. I will keep testing it and modifying it. Please let me know if you encounter the same issue.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include a terminal return statement. In each method any `return` should return an empty string: `return '';` - this should force compliance with the spec.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226716/discussion-between-pshivvy-and-randy-casburn).